# I am not able to get Exact frame and not able to select exact element using selenium web drive

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
    <script>
        document.cookie='_srn=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 0000 00:00:00 GMT;';    
    </script>    
    <script>
        var strWindowId = "3pfb5VLw8QBMYH8eEuW2DFosHws0sm6e8da7mBeEXqsb";
    </script>
    <script language="javascript">
        navigator.id = "1433841867";</script>
    <script language="javascript">
        top._swescript = window;
    </script>
    <script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/rtcEditor.js"></script>    
    <script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/swecommon_top.js"></script>    
    <script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/swecommon.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/navctrl.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="23016/scripts/sweutil_keyboard.js"></script>
</head>

    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="No" onunload="SWEUnloadApp(&quot;/esales_enu/start.swe&quot;,&quot;&quot;,&quot;3pfb5VLw8QBMYH8eEuW2DFosHws0sm6e8da7mBeEXqsb&quot;)">
        <frame name="_sweclient" title="" src="/esales_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GetCachedFrame&amp;SWEACn=20956&amp;SWEC=1&amp;SWEFrame=top._sweclient&amp;SRN=3pfb5VLw8QBMYH8eEuW2DFosHws0sm6e8da7mBeEXqsb" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="" scrolling="No" cd_frame_id_="295be8d5723232bd8677e4a4e252aa46">
        <frame name="_swe" title="" src="/esales_enu/start.swe?SWECmd=GetCachedFrame&amp;SWEACn=20956&amp;SWEC=1&amp;SWEFrame=top._swe&amp;SRN=3pfb5VLw8QBMYH8eEuW2DFosHws0sm6e8da7mBeEXqsb" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="" scrolling="No" tabindex="-1">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

this is the actually i am getting in the HTML source this is not expected because  .i want Click below Attribute but same i am not getting in the Above HTML source. when i  Do Manually Inspect Element I will get below attribute but same when i run my script .I am Getting No Element Found Exception and No frame Exception found

```
<input type="text" name="s_1_1_102_0" value="" style="width:132" id="s_1_1_102_0" tabindex="2997" maxlength="255">
```

Please Help me to Resolve this if my above Comment is not Enough .please ask me for more details

Comment: I can't entirely follow your problem, could you try editing to explain what your code should do and what the error result is? Ideally paste the full error message into your question.

Comment: Could you also post the url of the site in question?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the element has not loaded by that time. try implementing waits on your code. Good detailed information can be found here - 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If it is a synchronization issue you can try the code below:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iFrame")));
```